# How to grab inner JSON map

Tags: java, json, gson

Im trying to get specific values from the map.

I need to get value assigned to "leaguePoints", "tier", "rank", for
"queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5" && "playerOrTeamName": "Invicterr".

I added code I try below.

I think I need to iterate entries:[], but I have no idea how to to this.
Im a total JSON newbie, and Java begginer.

Map:

```
"32303008": {
  "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
  "name": "Sejuani's Berserkers",
  "entries": [
     {
        "isHotStreak": false,
        "isFreshBlood": false,
        "leagueName": "Sejuani's Berserkers",
        "miniSeries": {
           "progress": "LWN",
           "target": 2,
           "losses": 1,
           "timeLeftToPlayMillis": 0,
           "wins": 1
        },
        "isVeteran": false,
        "tier": "PLATINUM",
        "lastPlayed": 0,
        "playerOrTeamId": "21747474",
        "leaguePoints": 100,
        "rank": "V",
        "isInactive": false,
        "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "playerOrTeamName": "sunchasee",
        "wins": 127
     },
     {
        "isHotStreak": false,
        "isFreshBlood": false,
        "leagueName": "Sejuani's Berserkers",
        "isVeteran": false,
        "tier": "PLATINUM",
        "lastPlayed": 1389198358615,
        "playerOrTeamId": "32303008",
        "leaguePoints": 64,
        "rank": "V",
        "isInactive": false,
        "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "playerOrTeamName": "Invicterr",
        "wins": 462
     }
  ],
  "tier": "PLATINUM"
}
```

My code:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, League> entry : leagues.entrySet())
{
 try
 {
     if(Integer.parseInt(entry.getKey()) == 32303008)
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "|" + entry.getValue());
        }
 }
 catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Comment: Step 1) Convert the JSON string to a set of nested maps and arrays using one of about a dozen different toolkits.  Step 2) "Chain" access through map entry "32303008", map entry "entries", array element zero, map entry "leaguePoints".  Etc for the other values.  No iteration required.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using something like [JSON Simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/).  This will convert your JSON to a Java object that will be more simple to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
Map jsonMain = JSONParser.parse(myJSONSourceString);
Map numberedEntry = (Map)(jsonMain.get("3203008"));
List entries = (List)(numberedEntry.get("entries"));
for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++) {
    Map theEntry = (Map)(entries.get(0));
    String queueType = (String)(theEntry.get("queueType"));
    String playerOrTeamName = (String)(theEntry.get("playerOrTeamName"));
    if (queueType.equals("RANKED_SOLO_5x5") && (playerOrTeamName.equals("Invicterr")) {
        Number leaguePoints = (Number)(theEntry.get("leaguePoints"));
        int leaguePointsValue = leaguePoints.intValue();
        String tier = (String)(theEntry.get("tier"));
        String rank = (String)(theEntry.get("rank"));
        // Do something with the values
        break;
    }
}
```

The precise types and method names (and whether casting is needed) will depend on which JSON kit you use.